# Update user info in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am studying spring boot now.
I'm trying to update user information on DB now, but when I run it, it only select in DB and there's a problem that the information I'm trying to update doesn't put in DB.

It's my update part in Entity.

```
    public void updateUser(UserUpdateDto dto, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        if(dto.getPassword() != null) this.password = passwordEncoder.encode(dto.getPassword());
        if(dto.getName() != null) this.name = dto.getName();
        if (dto.getTel() != null) this.tel = dto.getTel();
    }
```

This is Service part

```
    @Override
    public UserResponseDto getMyInfo() {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(SecurityUtil.getLoginUserId())
                .map(UserResponseDto::of)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(""));
    }



    @Override
    public void updateMyInfo(UserUpdateDto dto) {
        User user = userRepository
                .findByEmail(SecurityUtil.getLoginUserId())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(""));

        user.updateUser(dto, passwordEncoder);
    }
```

This is my Dto.

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserResponseDto {
    private String Name;
    private String tel;
    private String password;


    public static UserResponseDto of(User user) {
        return new UserResponseDto(user.getName(), user.getTel(), user.getPassword());
    }
}
```

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserUpdateDto {
    @NotBlank(message = "")
    private String name;
    @NotBlank(message = "")
    private String tel;
    @NotBlank(message = "")
    private String password;

}
```

And it's controller

```
    @PutMapping("/update")
    public ResponseEntity<UserResponseDto> updateMyInfo(@RequestBody UserUpdateDto dto) {
        userService.updateMyInfo(dto);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getMyInfo());
    }
```

Thank you in advance to everyone who cares and helps.

Comment: i think, you need to call this code ```repositoryObj.save(user);``` to ensure it gets updated in database

Comment: I put repository.save in the service and it's solved!
Thank you very much :)